# Fortran Pointer

Tags: pointers, fortran

I'm trying to write a subroutine using already existing `common` blocks. And I don't understand how they use the pointer feature.

There is a section like this:

```
parameter (ncvarmx=101) 
pointer (pfmxarcval,fmxarcval(ncvarmx,*))! max/min values for current postvalue and body
                                               ! min for this inc and ibody
                                               ! max for this inc and ibody
                                               ! min from begin to this inc and ibody
                                               ! max from begin to this inc and ibody
common/marc_archp/parcelcd,parcellbl,parcndcd,parcndlbl,pfmxarcval 
real*8 fmxarcval
```

I basically need the values from `fmxarcval`. I assume there are 3 of them, although it is not a vector.

How can I use such a pointer?

Comment: That looks like a use of the non-standard but widely implemented feature of *Cray pointers*, which should not be confused with the concept of pointers that was introduced with Fortran 90.  It's so long since I used Cray pointers that I have only a vague memory of their use, so I won't offer what might be wonky advice.  But, armed with the term *Cray pointers* fire up your favourite search engine.  In passing, I don't understand why you assume that there are 3 values in `fmxarcval`, there is nothing in the snippet you've posted to support that assumption.

Comment: I assume the 3 values, based on the Description, that it inherits the Values for x,y and z direction. 

I'll try the Cray pointers. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Well it seems that the pointer 'pfmxarcval' points to an array 'fmxarcval' of size 'ncvarmx' x '*'. 
That how it is documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5263/aevmr/index.html .

On the other hand, fmxarcval ist declared as an array. 

I will not change it, since it isn't my commen block and used by a other Program. So i'll try and find an other approch to my Problem.

Comment: Strictly the pointer is an integer representation of the memory address of the pointee.  The pointee becomes, when the pointer is associated with a memory location, the way to dereference the pointer.  In effect the pointee becomes an alias for a variable whose address is the target of the pointer.  The snippet you've posted doesn't include the statement where the pointer is pointed at a memory location.  If the code works then either (a) don't touch it with a bargepole, or (b) rewrite it into modern Fortran.  I try always to take the latter course, but you seem constrained to take the former

Comment: I search for the statament where the pointer ist pointed, but could find it, i assume it is in one of the FEM-subroutines. so i better do not touch it an look out for an other way to get the values. 

Thank you for your Help.